# How can I pass data from blade view to modal and change the modal layout based on data I passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

May I ask are there any ways to pass data from view to modal? I have a request table and I want the modal to show the details after the user clicks the table row.

( I have four request type, when user click the table row of type1, the modal will have the layout for this type1, when user click the table row of type2, the modal layout will change)

Currently, I am using Jquery to show the data on the input tag but I want to change the layout of the modal according to the request type. How can I change the layout of modal if the type change? Can I pass the data dynamically into the modal so the modal can have this kind of logic *if ( $application->request_type == category1)*

```
        $('#application_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            var recipient = button.data('application')

            var modal = $(this)
            // modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
            if (recipient['request_category'] == "category1"){
                modal.find('.modal-body #Date_of_Calibration').val(recipient['New_Calibration_Date'].toString())
                modal.find('.modal-body #application-category').val(recipient['request_category'])
                modal.find('.modal-body #Next_Due_Date').val(recipient['Next_Due_Date'])
            }
            else if(recipient['request_category'] == "category2")"{
            ...
            }
            else if(recipient['request_category'] == "category3")"{
            ...
            }
            else
        })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you just redirect user to new blade?

Comment: @BabakAsadzadeh you mean create a new livewire component and a new route for the modal?

Comment: no just add a parameter in your url for example ```url/?blade=blade2``` and in your controller tell him to return ```blade2's blade``` if ```blade=blade2```